# How do I generate these horizontal lines in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Matplotlib Picture

[image: Matplotlib Picture]

I'm trying to add horizontal lines like the ones in the picture with a period length of 5. How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The black step function can be drawn with `plt.step()`. The red and blue horizontal lines with `plt.hlines()`:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

N = 150
x = np.random.uniform(0.1, 2, N).cumsum()
y = np.random.normal(0.01, 0.2, N).cumsum()
plt.step(x, y, color='black')
for color in ('red', 'blue'):
    xc = np.linspace(x[0], x[-1], N) + np.random.normal(0, 0.1, N)
    yc = np.interp(xc, x, y) + np.random.normal(0, 0.1, N)
    plt.hlines(yc, xc, xc + 5, colors=color, lw=0.5)
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]